# small issue [self doesIntersect] not working anymore

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

***If you can spot out all the [self doesIntersect] lines and all the [self doesIntersectWithCheckpoint] then i am wondering what is wrong with that code. It worked fine for a couple of days then xcode started giving me this error message about it "Instance method '-doesIntersect' not found (return type defaults to "id")" PLEASE HELP!***

```
#import "SecondLevelViewController.h"

@interface SecondLevelViewController ()

@end
@implementation SecondLevelViewController

float dx, dy;
int score = 0;

- (void)moving{

user.center = CGPointMake(user.center.x + dx, user.center.y + dy);
if ([self doesIntersect]){
    user.center = CGPointMake(user.center.x - dx, user.center.y - dy);
    dx = 0;
    dy = 0;
}
}

- (IBAction)goUp:(id)sender{

dx = 0;
dy = -1;
}

- (IBAction)goDown:(id)sender{

dx = 0;
dy = 1;
}

- (IBAction)goright:(id)sender{

dx = 1;
dy = 0;
}

- (IBAction)goLeft:(id)sender{

dx = -1;
dy = 0;
}

-(BOOL)doesIntersect {
[self intersectWithCheckpoint];
for (int i = 0; i < [blockArray count]; i++) {
    UIImageView *blk = [blockArray objectAtIndex:i];
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(user.frame, blk.frame)) {

        return YES;
    }

}
return NO;
}

- (void)setScore{

score = (score + 1);
scoreCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", score];
}

- (IBAction)resetAnimation:(id)sender{

user.center = CGPointMake(460, 150);
winLabel.text = @"";
goToNextLevel.hidden = YES;
}

- (void)intersectWithCheckpoint {

if (CGRectIntersectsRect(user.frame, checkpoint.frame)){
    dx = 0;
    dy = 0;

    goToNextLevel.hidden = NO;
    winLabel.text = @"YOU WIN!";
    [scoreTimer invalidate];

}
}

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
goToNextLevel.hidden = YES;

//blocks
[super viewDidLoad];
score = 0;

mainTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval : (0.01) target : self selector :     @selector(moving) userInfo : nil repeats : YES];


blockArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:block, block1, block2, block3, block4,               block5, block6, block7, block8, block9, block10, block11, block12, block13, block14, block15,   block16, block17, block18, block19, block20, block21, block22, nil];

scoreTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.00) target:self     selector:@selector(setScore) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:    (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

`doesIntersectWithCheckpoint` doesn't exist in your listed code.  Presumably you meant `intersectWithCheckpoint`.

`doesIntersect` appears to be defined.  I'd suggest you try "cleaning" your project and rebuilding.